Как получить всех подписчиков в телеграм канале?
Я написал небольшой код который по идеи должен получать всех подписчиков в моем телеграмм канале, но получает только 202 подписчика! В чём может быть ошибка? Я использую библиотеку telethon
Вот код:
async def get_number_arabic_subs(channel_id: int) -> int:
    """
    We get the number of Arabic subscribers
    :param channel_id: ID Channel
    :return: The number captions in the channel
    """
    offset = 0
    limit = 100
    all_users = []

    async with TelegramClient("client", API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
        channel = await client.get_entity(channel_id)
        while True:
            result = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(
                channel=channel, filter=ChannelParticipantsSearch(''),
                offset=offset, limit=limit, hash=0
            ))

            users = result.users
            all_users.extend(users)
            if len(users) < limit:
                break
                
            offset += limit
        
        print(len(all_users))

